# Can someone explain this conditional assignment?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble understanding the following line:

```
result = (status!=None and "off" or "on")
```

Now when this is called, only `status` has been assigned a value (the result of a regular expression search). However, after this command, `result` takes the value of "on" or "off".

To my untrained eye, this just looks like a comparison. How is this assignment happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Furthermore, any non-empty string is considered to be "true" when it appears in a boolean context.

With this, we can tackle your question.

Due to operator precedence rules, the following:

```
status != None and "off" or "on"
```

is equivalent to:

```
(status != None and "off") or "on"
```

The first part, `status != None and "off"` evaluates to:

- `False` if `status` is `None`;
- `"off"` otherwise

The entire expression, `(status != None and "off") or "on"` evaluates to:

- `"on"` if `status` is `None`;
- `"off"` otherwise.

An arguably more Pythonic way to write this statement is:

```
result = "on" if status is None else "off"
```

Comment: and one of the reasons for the new syntax introduced in the 'arguably more pythonic way' was to prevent people from writing that ugly short-circuited logic crap